# Problems with user selecting value outside of Enum range

Tags: c#, enums

I want the user to be able to type in a choice and have the program match their choice with one of the `enum` options. I have it set up in a loop so the user can keep trying if their entry doesn't match (i.e. `Apple`, `Banana`, `Carrots`).

```
enum Food {Apple, Banana, Carrot};

Food foodChoice;
while (!(Enum.TryParse<Food>(Console.ReadLine(), true, out foodChoice)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid choice.");
}
```

This all works fine and dandy until the user enters, say `5`. Obviously the `Food` enum doesn't have that many options and the `TryParse` will still output `true`, assigning `foodChoice` to 5. Is there a simple way to handle this?

Comment: @MikeChristensen No it won't. https://ideone.com/olmbqy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way would be to see if the string holds integer or not.

```
Food foodChoice;
int n;
string temp;
while (!(Enum.TryParse<Food>(temp = Console.ReadLine(), true, out foodChoice)) || int.TryParse(temp,out n))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid choice.");
}
```

Comment: @downvoter Dude, This is the simplest way. (well not writing less code but if there is any problem here i appreciate tolet me know.)

Comment: @PatrickHofman hmm i thought OP wants to only accept with names, not numbers. If OP unmark this answer ill definitely delete it.( But i guess thats what op wants?  ;))

Comment: Maybe it does what OP wants. Or maybe he doesn't know the implications of your code and he will come back some time later to get your code fixed ;)

Comment: Yea, question is completely unclear.  Do they want numbers that map to a single Enum value to be accepted?  If so, all these answers are wrong.  But if that's the case, why was this answer accepted as correct?

Comment: I guess OP doesn't know you can combine enum values and still remain a valid value. Hence he doesn't know why this behavior happens. With this code it seems to work, so OP accepts is.

Comment: This worked for what I am doing. I haven't had a lot of experience with enums. The code example is just made up since my actual code is for school work. I needed the user to type in a string that matched with 3 options in the enum. If I entered numbers (other than integer that matched the index of the enum choices) it would accept the number and my program wouldn't work. Also for everyone wondering why I chose this as correct, it is because it was one of the first solutions and it worked. Sorry to cause so much mayhem.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use the [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Food foodChoice;
while (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), true, out foodChoice)
    || !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), foodChoice))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid choice.");
}
```

Comment: IsDefined would be true with an existing int value. This could lead to silly mistakes... Better use `Enum.GetNames()`

Comment: @Shnugo, that's entirely dependent on how you use it. I would use it like this: `while (!Enum.TryParse<Food>(Console.ReadLine(), true, out foodChoice) || !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), foodChoice))`

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie we are thinking the same way.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) on this particular (and a little odd) behavior of `TryParse`:

> Note that this value need not be a member of the `TEnum` enumeration. ... If value is the string representation of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the TEnum enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is value converted to an integral type. If this behavior is undesirable, call the `IsDefined` method to ensure that a particular string representation of an integer is actually a member of `TEnum`.

So all you need to do is check if the value actually exists by calling [`IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) in addition to parsing the string value:

```
!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), foodChoice)
```

And now for the **why**? Integers are always treated as valid enum values. It doesn't check the actual value since it would require to calculate every possible combination of enum values. This is true since this is a valid enum value:

```
Food foodChoice = Food.Carrot|Food.Apple|Food.Banana;
```

In this case, there are just a few possible values, and a value of 5 is impossible. For longer enum the calculation can get enormous. That's why they omitted it in the parse step.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
    var x = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Food));
    var a = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), "Apple");
    var b = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), "2");
    var c = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), 2);
    var d = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Food), 4);
    var e = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Food)).Contains("Apple");
    var f = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Food)).Contains("2");
    //var f = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Food)).Contains(2); //won't compile...
```